# Read line comments in INI file

Tags: php, documentation, single-source

The [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function removes comments when reading configuration files.

What would you do to keep the comments that are associated with the next line?

For example:

> ```
> [email]
> ; Verify that the email's domain has a mail exchange (MX) record.
> validate_domain = true
> ```

Am thinking of using X(HT)ML and XSLT to transform the content into an INI file (so that the documentation and options can be single sourced). For example:

```
<h1>email</h1>
<p>Verify that the email's domain has a mail exchange (MX) record.</p>
<dl>
<dt>validate_domain</dt>
<dd>true</dd>
</dl>
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use preg_match_all to extract comments after `[heading]` markups:

```
$txt = file_get_contents("foo.ini");
preg_match_all('/\[([^\]]*)\][[:space:]]*;(.*)/',
    $txt, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$html = '';

foreach ($matches as $val) {
    $key = trim($val[1]); /* trimming to handle edge case
                             "[ email ]" so $key can be looked up
                              in the parsed .ini */
    $comment = $val[2];

    $html .= "<h1>$key</h1>\n";
    $html .= "<p>$comment</p>\n";
}

echo $html;
```

foo.ini could contain:

```
[email]
; Verify that the email's domain has a mail exchange (MX) record.
validate_domain = true ; comment ignored

[s2] ; comment can go here too
foo_bar = true

[s3]
foo_bar = true ; comment also ignored
```

I didn't play around with parse_ini_file because I don't feel like rebooting to another OS with PHP 5.3, but I think it should be easy to generate the rest of the HTML.

Comment: I think `X(HT)ML -> INI` is a bit more flexible than `INI -> X(HT)ML`. (No edge cases.) However, I'm fairly certain your solution works. Thank you!